# HTTP service doesn't work

Tags: http, go, rpc

I'm trying to implement a RPC server in Go using Hprose. It worked fine but then after adding some more functions it didn't :/

Funny thing is that it doesn't work even on other http libraries such as fasthttp. The ListenAndServe() method just seems to be stuck somewhere during execution as it never returns. What might be causing this?

```
package main


import (
    "net/http"
    "fmt"
     "github.com/hprose/hprose-golang/rpc"
    log "logutil"
)

func main() {
    log.InitializeLogger()
    InitializeEthClient()
    InitializeClients()
    server := rpc.NewHTTPService()

    // TxtStorage functions
    server.AddFunction("DeployTxtStorage", DeployNewTxtStorage)
    server.AddFunction("GetPackedData", GetPackedData)
    server.AddFunction("GetReputation", GetReputation)
    server.AddFunction("GetEventsForReputation", GetEventsForReputation)
    server.AddFunction("GetEventsForData", GetEventsForData)

    // Clients functions
    server.AddFunction("RegisterClient", RegisterClient)

    log.Info("Registered server functions!")
    err := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", server)
    fmt.Println(err)
    log.Info("Waiting for incoming connections...")
    log.WriteAway()
}
```

Comment: If you don't give people a minimal broken example, you have no hope of an answer.

Comment: I didn't include any code because my work is split into various files containing the functions, the only code which has to do with http at all is a simple http.ListenAndServe() call. Anyways I'll include that

Comment: "it worked fine but then after adding some more functions it didn't" what was the change that caused the issue? What is the issue? "it worked fine then it didn't" isn't anything anyone can troubleshoot.

Comment: Added some functions -> Registered new rpc functions (server.AddFunction()) ... And there's really nothing else I can add to this, it looks like it simply doesn't want to work

Comment: ListenAndServe() is not supposed to return. How do you know that it doesn't work though ? What do you expect to happen ? Have you connected to your server ? What error message do you get if that fails and how did you test it ? Have you inspected your system using e.g. netstat to verify your program is or is not currently listening on port 8080 ?

Comment: Nope it is not listening on port 8080 edit: tried it again now it's listening..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ListenAndServe is blocking, it won't return unless it hits an error. You seem to be expecting your final lines to print out

```
Waiting for incoming connections...
```

But that will never happen as the server is running. Are you sure it isn't just working as expected?

Comment: It is strange because it used to reach that line...? I'm really confused right now

Comment: We all have our moments :) this can be an unforgiving place so perhaps try some of the debugging steps outlined by nos above, and ask on a forum or golang nuts if still stuck.

Comment: It seems to be working =\ I'm wondering if it really reached that code line or perhaps I just saw a bunch of logs and thought that "Waiting for incoming connections..." was there too. Thanks for your time guys +1